# React useImperativeRef not updating until state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple component that's just two `input`s tied together, representing an (x, y) vector input.

I want a custom reference for this component to have the structure `{x, y}`.

I tried to do this with `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`. However, when using this and just trying to print the ref, I get the old version unless I force a state update.

Here's what I have: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-waterfall-730d6

How can I get the ref to update? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how references work? Why doesn't it update separate from component state?

```js
const { useRef, useState, useImperativeHandle } = React;

const Vec2Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { defaultValue = [0, 0], ...rest } = props;
  const xRef = useRef(null);
  const yRef = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    x: xRef.current.valueAsNumber,
    y: yRef.current.valueAsNumber
  }));

  return (
    <div {...rest}>
      <input
        type="number"
        ref={xRef}
        onClick={() => xRef.current.select()}
        defaultValue={defaultValue[0]}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        ref={yRef}
        onClick={() => yRef.current.select()}
        defaultValue={defaultValue[1]}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const vecRef = useRef(null);
  const [_forceUpdate, setForceUpdate] = useState({});

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Vec2Input ref={vecRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(`${vecRef.current.x}, ${vecRef.current.y}`);
        }}
      >
        Print values
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setForceUpdate({});
        }}
      >
        Force state update
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The refs are updated, but the object you created from the refs' in `useImperativeHandle` doesn't update without a render. Instead of an object, set the imperative handler to be a function, and call it from the parent component.

**Note**: I've removed the conditional chaining `?.` operator because it's not supported by stackoverflow's snippet.

```js
const { useRef, useState, useImperativeHandle } = React;

const Vec2Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { defaultValue = [0, 0], ...rest } = props;
  const xRef = useRef(null);
  const yRef = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => () => ({
    x: xRef.current.valueAsNumber,
    y: yRef.current.valueAsNumber
  }));

  return (
    <div {...rest}>
      <input
        type="number"
        ref={xRef}
        onClick={() => xRef.current.select()}
        defaultValue={defaultValue[0]}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        ref={yRef}
        onClick={() => yRef.current.select()}
        defaultValue={defaultValue[1]}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const vecRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Vec2Input ref={vecRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(vecRef.current());
        }}
      >
        Print values
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In the `Vec2Input` use `useState` instead of refs to update the data. Changing the state would cause a re-render, that would call `useImperativeHandle`, and update the outgoing ref.

```js
const { useRef, useState, useImperativeHandle } = React;

const Vec2Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { defaultValue = [0, 0], ...rest } = props;
  const [values, setValues] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => values);
  
  const setValue = ({ target }) => {
    setValues(s => ({ ...s, [target.name]: target.valueAsNumber }));
  };
  

  return (
    <div {...rest}>
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={setValue}
        name="x"
        defaultValue={defaultValue[0]}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={setValue}
        name="y"
        defaultValue={defaultValue[1]}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const vecRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Vec2Input ref={vecRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(vecRef.current);
        }}
      >
        Print values
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That makes sense, is there no way to get a custom ref to behave like the built-in objects? For instance this works fine if I just use the `input` ref directly: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-violet-ypwci